# updating the variable inside for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

My program objective is that to calculate how many shops I will have after a while. I provided the equation for the program to follow it. The cost of each shop is 30000$. I started with 3 shops and their income 10000$ / shop, so the total money I'll get from my shops is 30000$ / month.  Now, as given after one month I will be able to open new shop and my shops will increase to 4 and so on. After 7 months my shops will be 21 and total money must be 210000$. How would you modify the code to do that. If you want to make sure you can use paper to calculate it. The problem in my code is that once the total money reach 60000 and more, the program subtract 30000 and increase the counter and the shop by 1 whereas it must increase the counter once and the shop twice. Because 60000$ is the cost of 2 shops establishment and so on.

```
public class investmentCalculation 
    /** the class describe the plan of investment. Each shop costs 30000  */
        {
         private int income ;
         private int shop ;
         private int firstMoney ;
         private int totalMoney1;
         private int totalMoney;
        //instructor  
        public investmentCalculation( )
        {
          income =10000;
           shop = 3;
            /** here is the cost of shop establishment */
           firstMoney = 30000; 
           totalMoney1 = 0;
        }
         // here the method to achieve the goal
        public int SetFor()
        { for(int i= 0; i < 7; i++)
        {   
         totalMoney1 = totalMoney1 + totalMoney - firstMoney;
/**here is    0      =  0          + 60000      - 30000; 
   I got the total money from this equation
   totalMoney = shop * income;
              = 6    * 10000;


now the shop should be 8. However, after compiling the program the output is 7.


         shop++;
         totalMoney = shop * income; /** once the TotalMoney = 30000(FirstMoney) should open new shop and so on. Once the iteration reach i=7 the TotalMoney must be 210000 */  

        shop++;
         totalMoney = shop * income;

         }
             System.out.println("the total money is: "+totalMoney);
             return shop;}


            }


            /** this class to test the investmentCalculation*/
            public class investmentCalculationTester 
           {

            public static void main(String [] args)
           {
            investmentCalculation TT = new investmentCalculation();
            int A =  TT.SetFor();
            System.out.println("the shops are:   "+A);

            }}
```

Comment: Your formatting *surely* can't be helping in any way.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Yep, that's the quickest way to piss of other developers. Especially on SO.

Comment: For one thing, you have a line that appears to compute the sum of something, but then you never use the sum.  That looks like a simple typo.  But if the result is still wrong, either use a debugger or use `System.out.println` to print the values of some key variables inside the loop so that you can see where things are going wrong.  I can't tell what's going wrong since I have no idea what you're trying to compute.

Comment: Hi user3718703 - welcome to Stack overflow! I notice that you tried to edit one of the answers to provide a response to their help. That's not the best way to go about responding to their answer. Feel free to leave a comment on @pwmilmot's answer instead. That way we can remember what pwilmot said as well as hearing your response. You should be able to comment on any answers on your own question.

Comment: hey, you know it'd be quite helpful if you edited your question and added a copy of what the output really looks like for you right now. eg "the total money is: ... The total money is ..." etc

Comment: Secondly - why don't you put a print statement *inside* your looop (for now) so we can see how the numbers go for each iteration of the loop eg `System.out.println("i is " + i + " totalmoney1 is: " + TotalMoney1 + " totalMoney is: " + totalMoney);` (note: I haven't tested this line it might have bugs... just fix it so it works).

Comment: Although it might seem like a formality to a new programmer, creating self-explaining variable and method names is extremely important. I'm not able to help you because I don't understand what totalmoney1, totalmoney and firstmoney are meant to be used for. I would recommend to focus on better names =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think you should recalculate the total money. Because number of shops is 21, is correct. Please recalculate total money; it can never be 210000.

```
public class investmentCalculation {
private int income;
private int shop;
private int firstMoney;
private int totalMoney1;
private int shopsAdded;

public investmentCalculation() {
    income = 10000;
    shop = 3;
    firstMoney = 30000;
    totalMoney1 = 0;
    shopsAdded = 0;
}

// here the method to achieve the goal
public int SetFor() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        totalMoney1 += income * shop;
        shopsAdded = totalMoney1 / firstMoney;  //Calculate how many shops can be added with the money you have.
        shop += shopsAdded;                     //Increment the shops by the newly added shops.
        totalMoney1 -= firstMoney * shopsAdded; //Decrement the cost required to form the new shops.
    }
    System.out.println("the total money is: " + totalMoney1);
    return shop;
}

/** this class to test the investmentCalculation */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    investmentCalculation TT = new investmentCalculation();
    int A = TT.SetFor();
    System.out.println("the shops are:   " + A);
}
```

}`